# Select records from database based on condition/tags

Tags: database

I would like to build a database where each record has some tags.  Then I want to output some fields of the records that contain a given tag.  If it is possible, I would also like to output the records that contain at least one tag from a given set of tags (that is, non empty intersection with the record's tags), or even the records that fulfill a certain condition based on tags (for instance, the records that contains certain tags but not other tags).  What is the best way to do that in LaTeX and friends?

Additional information:  My records are exercises.  My fields are question, answer, date, tags, etc.  Tags are the subjects of each exercise (each exercise may cover several subjects).

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but may be you will find interesting [AMC](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/).